# Excel vba plot showing worksheet name + page number/adding title page in plot

Tags: vba, excel

I made the following script to automatic plot the active worksheet to a certain layout, in the right footer I would like to show the name of the active worksheet followed by the page number, 'edit: found the 'Activesheet.Name' formula, but still don't know how to add the page number (layout of page number: actual page numer/total amount of pages)

Example of a wanted right footer:
PartA - 1/12

Is it btw also possible to include a front page with just the name of the current worksheet, displayed in a big font in the center? Or is it needed to design the excel worksheet that way that the first page just contains one active cell with the title in the center?

```
Application.PrintCommunication = False
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A:$N"
    .PrintTitleRows = ""
    .PrintTitleColumns = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = ""
    .CenterHeader = "PROJECT X"
    .RightHeader = ""
    .LeftFooter = Sheets("instellingen").Cells(20, 2).Value
    .CenterFooter = Sheets("instellingen").Cells(22, 2).Value
    .RightFooter = ""
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .PrintHeadings = False
    .PrintGridlines = False
    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    .PrintQuality = 600
    .CenterHorizontally = False
    .CenterVertically = False
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .Draft = False
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .Order = xlDownThenOver
    .BlackAndWhite = False
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 0
    .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
    .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
    .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
    .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = ""
    .PrintTitleColumns = ""
End With
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I answered the footer question below. Please limit your question to **one** actual question. That said, to answer the design question, yes, you will need to create your own title sheet with a separate tab (or at the beginning of the printed sheet with relevant page breaks. Also, you can clean up your code quiet a bit by only using the methods that you need to specifically change. The rest of defaults and will process anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are looking for a syntax, recording a macro while you do the manual steps can be very helpful.

I used Excel's built-in `Page 1 of ?` custom filter to get the syntax you are after. Manually, I went to Page Layout > Page Setup > Header / Footer > Footer > Page 1 of ?

```
.RightFooter = ActiveSheet.Name & " - " & "Page &P of &N"
```

Comment: found the rest of the syntax using the macro recording funtion, feeling pretty stupid to not think about this, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can really force a page number, since you don't know how many pages there are.  So it's the same as setting it in regular Excel.

Try this `Page &[Page] of &[Pages]`

Regular format taken from https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-remove-page-numbers-57ebb99e-0cfc-408b-864a-c805b5040ae7

- Side note, isn't using `.PageSetup` slow? I can't remember if they fixed it or not? There is a trick with using the print setup from the Excel4 Macros that was much faster.

Comment: I used the macro record tool, don't know if theres another way. So far, the running time didn't bother me, runs pretty quick in my opinion

Comment: You would notice...you know that pause that it takes when you select a new printer...it did that for every single setting.